# Set a particular string in a paragraph as HTML in JEditorPane using Swing

Tags: java, html, swing, hyperlink, jeditorpane

I am designing a Swing application which gets results in a JEditorPane. The results retrieved have urls in it. I want only the urls to be displayed as HTML as URLS should be given as hyperlinks.

I tried the following code:

```
JEditorPane textarea;
String s=""
/*some code here*/
    void prettyPrint(PrintStream out, SolrDocument doc) {
            List<String> sortedFieldNames =
                    new ArrayList<String>(doc.getFieldNames());
            Collections.sort(sortedFieldNames);
            out.println();

            for (String field : sortedFieldNames) {
                if(field.equals("content")){

                    s += String.format("%s: %s",
                            field,doc.getFieldValue(field)+"\n");
                    textarea.setText(s);
                    out.println(String.format("\t%s: %s",
                            field, doc.getFieldValue(field)));
                    contentsmethod1(doc.getFieldValue(field).toString());
                    //  contents.add(doc.getFieldValue(field).toString());
                    //  System.out.println("conetnts"+contentstring);

                }
                if((!field.equals("content")) && (!field.equals("url"))){

                    s += String.format("%s: %s",
                            field,doc.getFieldValue(field)+"\n");
                    textarea.setText(s);
                    out.println(String.format("\t%s: %s",
                            field, doc.getFieldValue(field)));
                }
                if(field.equals("url")){

                    final String url = doc.getFieldValue(field).toString();


                    String link = "<a href=\"'"+url+"'\"target=\"_blank\">"+url+"</a>";
                    textarea.setContentType("text/html");
                    s+=link;
                    textarea.setText(s);
    }
    }
    }
```

**First problem:**
In the above code I have retrieved my results and appending it to JEditorPane. It works fine. But everything is turned to html as I have set the textarea.setContenttype("text/html"). I want only my urls to be html and rest to be normal text.

**Second problem:**

And also the url links are not opening the browser onclick of it. How do I redirect it to browser?

Comment: Can you clarify your first problem? `html` should be rendered as such when the content type of the document is set to `html`. Do you want all `html` to be rendered like text (__including__ the elements and styles) __except__ <a> elements, which should be rendered as a link (eg without rendering the <a> tag)?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Hard code some typical data that contains both URLs and 'plain text'.

Comment: These are 2 different questions with 2 sets of different answers. Ask them separately. Voting to close as "too broad".

Comment: @copeg : My problem is i want only the <a> tag to be rendered as html and rest all as plain text. As I am setting the entire JEditorPane to html I am facing this problem. For instance : I am working in so and so organization. And the website of that organization is www.example.com
For the above sentence I just want the url to be a html and rest all as plain text. How can I set it?